# How to serve html files from XAMPP apache server in windows

Tags: python, html, apache

I have an html file which calls a python script to display some data from the form action tag. I want to run them through XAMPP on windows. I put my files in the cgi-bin folder after creating a subfolder named `CGIPython`. If I call the html file as

```
http://localhost:82/cgi-bin/CGIPython/Test.html
```

I get `"The website cannot display the page"` error. Even if I try a bare minimum `.html` file, I get the same error. However if I call my `.py` page directly, it works fine. I have this line in my `httpd.conf` file:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp .py .html
```

I also tried putting the html files in the `htdocs` folder.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use `SimpleHttpServer` or `CGIHttpServer` to serve files?

Comment: First try to use `test.py` in `/cgi-bin/` and this script have to `print` all `html` (with `http header`). You can't mix `html` with python code like in `.php` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to use `test.py` in `/cgi-bin/` and this script have to `print` all `html` (with `http header`). You can't mix `html` with python code like in `.php` file.

As default Apache runs only scripts in `/cgi-bin/` so even `/cgi-bin/CGIPython` may needs some modifications in congif file.

Apache runs `.py`, `.pl` using operation system (Windows) and Windows knows what to do with this - it runs `python` or `perl`. But Windows don't know what to do with `.html` - is it python, perl or other language ?

Better use `.htaccess` to convert name `/test.html` to `/cgi-bin/test.py`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^test.html$ cgi-bin/test.py
```

or for all files

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ cgi-bin/$1.py
```